# In R, what is the best way to write loop within a loop for a character string?

Tags: r

> Looking into a web crawler that will go through multiple indeed.com
> country URLs
>
> I have the first part of the code that crawls through individual pages
> below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

listings<- data.frame(title=character(),
                      company=character(),
                      stringAsFactors = FALSE)

for(i in seq(0,500,10)){
   url_ds<-paste0('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=&radius=25&start=',i)
   var <-read_html(url_ds)

#job title
title<- var %>%
    html_nodes('#resultsCol .jobtitle') %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_extract("(//w+,+)+")

#company
    company<- var %>%
    html_nodes('#resultsCol .company') %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_extract("(//w+,+)+")

 listings<-rbind(listings, as.data.frame(cbind(company,
                                          title)))
 }
```

> What I would like to do is also loop through an array of the different
> country urls at the beginning of the "url_ds" above using a
> url_basic_list below and add a column for the actual country.
> basically I would need to create a loop within a loop for a text
> string, what is the best way to do so?

```
url_basic_list<-
     c("http://www.indeed.com",
     "http://www.indeed.com.hk",
     "http://www.indeed.com.sg"
     )

country<-
     c("USA",
     "Hong Kong",
     "Singapore"
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

- change your `for` loop to `lapply`; this is mostly because iteratively adding rows to a `data.frame` starts out okay but gets slower and more memory-intensive with each pass through the loop. (For each `rbind`, it has to copy all of the contents in memory, so your memory needs are at least *double* the size of the frame.) By using `lapply`, it creates a [list of `data.frame`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227) (read the link!), which is created and filled memory-efficiently (as much as R can do), and then we do a single `rbind` at the end on the whole dataset.
- functionize this, and call the country code (`cc`) as a function argument.

```r
get_indeed <- function(cc = "") {
  dotcc <- if (cc == "us") "" else paste0(".", cc)

  listings_list <- lapply(seq(0, 500, by = 10), function(i) {
    url_ds <- sprintf('https://www.indeed.com%s/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=&radius=25&start=%i', dotcc, i)
    var <- read_html(url_ds)

    #job title
    title <- var %>%
      html_nodes('#resultsCol .jobtitle') %>%
      html_text() %>%
      str_extract("(//w+,+)+")

    #company
    company <- var %>%
      html_nodes('#resultsCol .company') %>%
      html_text() %>%
      str_extract("(//w+,+)+")

    data.frame(company, title)
  })
  listings <- do.call(rbind, listings_list)
  listings$cc <- if (nzchar(cc)) cc else ""
  listings
}
```

From here, to "loop" through a series of countries, one might do

```r
all_countries <- lapply(c("us", "hk", "sg"), get_indeed)
all_countries <- do.call(rbind, all_countries)
```

From here, all of your `$cc` values will be the two-letter codes, which is fine. The bring in the full names, I suggest you have a simple `data.frame` to map one to the other:

```r
countries <- data.frame(
  cc = c("us", "hk", "sg"),
  country = c("USA", "Hong Kong", "Singapore")
)
all_countries <- merge(all_countries, countries, by = "cc")
```

And your data will now have both `$cc` (two-letter) and `$country` (full words).

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting an error "Error in Open.Connection(x, "rb")

Comment: "SNI or certificate failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - the target is incorrect"  Any thoughts?

Comment: If you look up that error (it's not uncommon), a common cause is that your client (browser or `httr`) does not trust the certificate. If you go to `indeed.com.hk` *yourself* and examine its certificate, you should notice that the SSL certificate is meant for `*.parkingcrew.net`, suggesting that indeed.com.hk is either not being used properly or is being mis-routed.